# Sort View Alphabetically with Django View

Tags: python, django

I have a view that returns a model called Solution.

```
def index(request):
    things = Solution.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'things': things,
    })
```

How would I go about having this sorted alphabetically? I saw that there is this option:
Main.objects.order_by('name')

How could I fit that into my current view?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your queryset:

```
def index(request):
    things = Solution.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'things': things,
    })
```

You'll have to adjuste the `name` to the atribute you want to use for ordering from the `Solution` model

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    things = Solution.objects.order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'things': things,
    })
```

You can find more details about order_by in Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)